# fillMaxSize modifier not working when combined with VerticalScroll in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried looking this up but could not find anything relevant.

I want to have a "full size" `Column` inside a vertically scrollable `Box` and this combination just doesn't seem to work. when I add the `verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` modifier to the `Box`, it seems to "disable" the `fillMaxSize()` modifier of the `Column`

The following code does **not** work as expected:

```
MyTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green) //for visual effect only
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red) //for visual effect only
            ) {
               //some content
            }
        }
}
```

**Expected result:** Both `Box` and `Column` (green and red borders) fill the entire screen.

**Actual result:** `Box` fills the screen, but `Column` does not fill height

[image]

However if I remove the `verticalScroll()` modifier from the `Box`, I get the expected result:

```
MyTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green) //for visual effect only
                //verticalScroll modifier removed
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red) //for visual effect only
            ) {
               //some content
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try putting the verticalScroll modifier on the inner column. Since it is already filling the maxsize of the box, I don't see why you would want to put a vertical scroll on the box.

Comment: @Rafsanjani this fixes my specific issue so thanks, however my intention was also to understand why this is happening. so even though i used your solution, i have accepted Philip Dukhov's answer

Comment: For `LazyColumn` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949935/how-to-make-a-lazy-column-item-occupy-the-complete-height-in-jetpack-compose.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As @AjayChandran [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76362040/3585796), the simples solution is to add `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` after `verticalScroll` modifier.

This solution is simple, but may cause performance issues, since all the measurements inside the view are gonna be done twice. If you have performance problems in prod app version, consider using constant height - see detailed explanation below.

```
Modifier
    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
```

---

`verticalScroll` wraps the height of the content, and can be stretched to very long, so the scope has `Constraints.Infinity` for `maxHeight` constraint.

From `fillMaxHeight` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxHeight(kotlin.Float))

> If the incoming maximum height is Constraints.Infinity this modifier will have no effect.

That's why you need to set `height` explicitly.

Consider switching to [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumn(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Function1))(which has [`fillParentMaxHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxHeight(kotlin.Float)) for this exact purpose) or to [`Pager`](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)(which is made explicitly for such cases).

Also, as @AdrianK pointer out, with regular `scrollable` you can wrap your view with `BoxWithConstraints`, and use `maxHeight` to set `height` of your view.

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        Column {
            repeat(2) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        // fillMaxWidth instead of fillMaxSize
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        // explicit height modifier
                        .height(this@BoxWithConstraints.maxHeight)
                        .padding(2.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                ) {
                    //some content
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i accepted this answer as it provides an explanation to why this was happening, however i actually used @Rafsanjani solution

Answer (score 8):

I know its late, but this seems to be working for me.

```
Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState).height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
```

This expanded the height to its maximum intrinsic size and also it is vertically scrollable.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap your layout into a `BoxWithConstraints`, which is not scrollable and grab the size from there:

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    val pageSize = this.maxHeight // already provided as Dp value
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green) //for visual effect only
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(pageSize)
                .padding(2.dp)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red) //for visual effect only
        ) {
            //some content
        }
        // just so we can scroll a bit further
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = pageSize).fillMaxWidth().height(72.dp))
    }
}
```

Comment: not a terrible idea, even though it feels a little bit like a hack. but for my specific case @Rafsanjani solution works and feels more "clean" so i went with that

Answer (score 1):

The solution with BoxWithConstraints pointed me to a working solution (in my case).

I wrap the Column in a **max sized BoxWithConstraints**. Then I set the height of the Column to Modifier.**heightIn(min=maxHeight)**. This way the column is at least "maxHeight" tall.

```
BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .heightIn(min = maxHeight)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            Text(text="This is at the bottom")
        }
    }
```

Comment: not work in mac chrome, only work in safari with fullscreen.