# Using Modifier.fillMaxHeight() in Box doesn't display the element

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display a shadow at the start and end of a list to indicate that the list still has contents to the left/right.

I want the shadow to be as tall as the whole row so therefore I use `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()`. Unfortunately this doesn't work unless I specifiy the size of the component at call time.

When I call the function as:

```
LazyRowWithShadows(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 12.dp),
    shadowColor = colorResource(R.color.blue_white),
    shadowAlphaStart = 0f, shadowAlphaEnd = 0.8f,
    shadowWidth = 48.dp
) {
    // Content
}
```

The shadows are not displayed, but the rest of the content is. I have to give the modifier a `height` to make it work eg:

```
LazyRowWithShadows(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(X.dp), // This is what makes it display, but requires knowing the height of the row
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 12.dp),
    shadowColor = colorResource(R.color.blue_white),
    shadowAlphaStart = 0f, shadowAlphaEnd = 0.8f,
    shadowWidth = 48.dp
) {
    // Content
}
```

I would prefer if the `LazyRowWithShadows` handled displaying the shadows even if no size is specified when calling it. Is there an easy way to do this?

This is the code for the `LazyRowWithShadows`:

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

/**  A LazyRow that shows start & end shadows when content is not fully scrolled. */
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun LazyRowWithShadows(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        shadowColor: Color = Color.Black,
        shadowAlphaStart: Float = 0f,
        shadowAlphaEnd: Float = 0.3f,
        shadowWidth: Dp = 32.dp,
        content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    val showStartShadow by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset > 0 || listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
        }
    }

    val showEndShadow by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val lastItemIfVisible = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.maxByOrNull { it.index }?.takeIf { it.index == listState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 }
            if (lastItemIfVisible != null) {
                val lastItemEndX = lastItemIfVisible.offset + lastItemIfVisible.size
                lastItemEndX > listState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset
            } else {
                true
            }
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        LazyRow(
                state = listState,
                contentPadding = contentPadding,
                content = content)

        // Start scroll shadow
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = showStartShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(shadowWidth)
                    .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart))))
            )
        }
        // End scroll shadow
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = showEndShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(shadowWidth)
                    .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd))))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I have tried the solution proposed in [fillMaxSize modifier not working when combined with VerticalScroll in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394543/fillmaxsize-modifier-not-working-when-combined-with-verticalscroll-in-jetpack-co), but it didn't solve my issue. The changes I made to try to solve it using that answer as inspiration are:

```
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = modifier) { // Changed to BoxWithConstraints
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        content = content)

    // Start scroll shadow
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showStartShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .height(this@BoxWithConstraints.maxHeight) // Changed from fillMaxHeight
            .width(shadowWidth)
            .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart))))
        )
    }
    // End scroll shadow
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showEndShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .height(this@BoxWithConstraints.maxHeight) // Changed from fillMaxHeight
            .width(shadowWidth)
            .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd))))
        )
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a `height` to the `AnimatedVisibility` elements, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work using the information in that post. I have updated my question to address this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out a couple of ways, using [`Modifier.onSizeChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onSizeChanged(kotlin.Function1)) to get the `height` of `LazyRow` finally made it work.

Convert this `height` to `dp` and pass it to `Modifier.height` for shadow's Box(s).

```
Box(modifier = modifier) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val heightDp = remember(height) { with(density){ height.toDp() } }
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged {
            height = it.height
        },
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        content = content)

    // Start scroll shadow
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showStartShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .height(heightDp)
            .width(shadowWidth)
            .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart))))
        )
    }
    // End scroll shadow
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showEndShadow, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .height(heightDp)
            .width(shadowWidth)
            .background(brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = listOf(shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaStart), shadowColor.copy(alpha = shadowAlphaEnd))))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. I didn't know there was an `onSizeChanged` modifier. I will be on the lookout for a more "elegant" solution, but this works nicely.