# Nested Listing in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to structure my composables this way:

```
Column ->   
    Tab(Child)
    HorizontalPager (Child)->   
         LazyColumn (Child of Horizontal Pager)
```

I want to have a toolbar with (scroll | enterAlways) attribute, then a tablayout under, then a list below the tablayout.

I tried this structure but I'm getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was
> measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is
> disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like
> LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a
> header before the list of items please add a header as a separate
> item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope.

This is the structure of what I currently have:

```
Box( 
   Modifier
     .fillMaxSize()
     .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection) 
) { 
    Column(){
       TabRow(
         
       ) {       
       }
                                     
       HorizontalPager(

       ) {
           LazyColumn {
           }   
       }
   }

   TopAppBar()
}
```

Is there any alternative way to achieve a nested Lazycolumn inside a HorizontalPager and the HorizontalPager will have Column as it's parent?

Comment: You can check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190976/how-to-achieve-multiple-header-and-body-elements-list-for-a-lazycolumn-in-compos/75219930#75219930. You can't measure a LazyColumn with an infinite max height so you need to limit it to a finite number. Modifier.heightIn(max) will limit it while you still can assign height to your LazyColumn between 0 and max height set in modifier

Comment: remove nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection) ，Example : LazyRow(modifier = Modifier, userScrollEnabled = false)

Comment: check this out maybe it might help [nested columns in compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165390/vertically-scrollable-component-was-measured-with-an-infinity-maximum-height-con/75525836#75525836)

Answer (score 0):

I gave the below code a try in android studio and did not have any crashes.

```
Box( 
   Modifier
     .fillMaxSize()
     .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection) 
) { 
    Column(){
       TabRow() { }                 
       HorizontalPager() {
           LazyColumn (modifier = Modifier.Height(200.dp)) {
           }   
       }
   }
   TopAppBar()
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working without changing anything. Weirdly, I couldn't reproduce the crash again. This approach works fine now