# LazyColumn inside a column not supported?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen where its a column of multiple items:

```
Child1()

Child2()

Child3()

}


but one of my child has a LazyColumn in it, 

 Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer
            )
        ) {

            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
}
```

but it throws error of `Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll())`.

What should i do?

i tried moving up my LazyColumn at top, but the problem is, items data is inside Child3 , so how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165390/vertically-scrollable-component-was-measured-with-an-infinity-maximum-height-con)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to limit your `LazyColumn` height somehow, for example pass an appropriate modifier to the composable with the `LazyColumn`:

```
Child(Modifier.weight(1f))
Child(Modifier.height(200.dp))
```

And then apply it:

```
Card(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
```