# Jetpack Compose - stop background resizing with keyboard

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack, android-background

I've added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my AndroidManifest.xml file to allow the textfield, button and text to move up, but the background is also re-sizing itself.  How can I stop this from happening?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {

            //Used to determine where the starting launch point of the app is
            val user by remember { mutableStateOf(Firebase.auth.currentUser) }
            AppNavigation(
                startDestination = if (user == null) {
                    ViewToDisplayKeys.SignInOrSignUp.toString()
                } else {
                    ViewToDisplayKeys.OnboardingStart.toString()
                }
            )

        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = "signInOrSignUp"
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable("signInOrSignUp") {
            SignInOrSignUpMasterView(navController = navController)
        }
        composable("onboarding") {
            OnboardingStartView(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the onCreate method, the code is as follows:

```
class SignInOrSignUp : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.sign_in_sign_up_background)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    SignInOrSignUpMasterView()
                }
            }

        }

    }
}


@Composable
fun SignInOrSignUpView() {

    Box {

        //Background image
        /*Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sign_in_sign_up_background),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            alpha = 0.50F,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
        )*/


        SignUpView()
    }

}
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me.  I have copy and pasted this entire code and my background is still resizing when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml config : `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ?

Comment: Yep, this was already in the .xml file before I copy and pasted in your code above?  Has this solution worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it works exactly correctly, if you are convenient, you can pass your code to github and send me the link, I can help you fix it

Comment: So I've managed to get this to work now, but how can I add the same image modifiers I had in my `Image`

`contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
alpha = 0.50F,
modifier = Modifier
.background(Color.White)
.fillMaxSize()`

Comment: Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.White.copy(alpha=0.5F))) {
        SignInOrSignUpMasterView()
}

Comment: I've done that now thanks.  Question now is when I introduce a new view and navigate to it, the background is always there.  I only want the background to be  a part of my `SignInOrSignUpMasterView()`.  Should I post a new question with my code or answer my own question and paste the new code there?

Comment: If you think my answer is useless, delete it

Comment: I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152716/jetpack-compose-create-background-which-doesnt-resize-with-keyboard-in-a-navi.

I will add this link as an answer to this question too if it gets answered.

Comment: I found it quite funny. You used the answer I gave you, but you said it was not solved, and you didn’t post all the code, and there was no video or GIF effect. Can you let us see the air?

Comment: @Vaz please accept the answer where you got help before asking a new question

Comment: Fair comments.  I have accepted this answer.  How can I attach a video to stackoverflow?  I couldn't find this online.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background to window:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.sign_in_sign_up_background)
```

Comment: Where in my `@Composable` does this link of code go?  My image code is above if you can help clarify.

Comment: Called in Activity's onCreate

Comment: So I've removed my `Image()` code and I've added the above line in several different places of my OnCreate but it doesn't show up when I run the simulator.  I've also added my OnCreate code above if that helps.

Comment: Put the @Composable method of your other parent container to remove the background color

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you copy and paste my code above into a new answer and paste in where the line of code needs to go?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with imePadding() where the background resized when I focused a text field.

The solution that worked for me was making sure imePadding() does not apply to the background image. So something like:

```kotlin
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
          Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
          Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, 
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                               .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                               .imePadding() 
           {
              //inside this column add the content you want to scroll
              //text fields, buttons, etc.
           }
    }
```

Modify horizontalAlignment and verticalArrangement as you need.

Note that Modifier.fillMaxSize() will not work with with the verticalScroll modifier (see: [fillMaxSize modifier not working when combined with VerticalScroll in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394543/fillmaxsize-modifier-not-working-when-combined-with-verticalscroll-in-jetpack-co)) which is why I'm using Modifier.fillMaxWidth() for the column instead.