# Implement pullRefresh on top of WebView (accompanist) in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Helo! I been having a hard time implementing SwipeRefreshLayout on top of my WebView. It seems like pullRefresh only takes a scrollable view inside it to be able to function.

I got it working by using on my WebView:
`Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`

However, the WebView content is not matching its parent height. I even used
`Modifier.fillMaxHeight()`
to fix it but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on a workaround? I just transitioned from XML to Compose.

```
    val webClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(
                view: WebView?,
                url: String?,
                favicon: Bitmap?
            ) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                // TODO()
            }
        }
    }

    val refreshScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    fun refresh() = refreshScope.launch {
        refreshing = true
        delay(1500)
        webViewNavigator.reload()
        refreshing = false
    }

    val state = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, ::refresh)

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .pullRefresh(state)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green) // for debugging purposes
    ) {
        WebView(
            state = webViewState,
            navigator = webViewNavigator,
            onCreated = { webView ->
                webView.apply {
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                }
            },
            client = webClient,
            captureBackPresses = false,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )

        PullRefreshIndicator(refreshing, state, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your WebView inside a Column/Box/Row/.. and add the verticalScroll modifier there. This works for AndroidView as well as WebView from Accompanist.

For web pages that are longer than the screen it works like a charm. But for shorter pages I couldn't get them to work in fullscreen yet.

You can read about the effects of verticalScroll here:
[fillMaxSize modifier not working when combined with VerticalScroll in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394543/fillmaxsize-modifier-not-working-when-combined-with-verticalscroll-in-jetpack-co)

The workarounds sadly only work for everything that is not a WebView. When implementing it you are not able to scroll anymore.

My example.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun TestWebView() {

    val refreshScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var itemCount by remember { mutableStateOf(15) }

    fun refresh() = refreshScope.launch {
        refreshing = true
        delay(1500)
        itemCount += 5
        refreshing = false
    }

    val state = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, ::refresh)
    val shortUrl = "http://www.corelangs.com/html/introduction/myfirstpage.html"
    val url = "https://google.com/"

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pullRefresh(state)
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    WebView(context).apply {
                        layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                        loadUrl(url)
                    }
                }, update = {
                    it.loadUrl(url)
                }
            )

            PullRefreshIndicator(
                refreshing = refreshing,
                state = state,
                Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `verticalScroll` workaround works in the sense that pull-to-refresh works; however, it breaks display of the webview itself fairly critically. As noted in the question, the viewport height of the resulting webview matches the full height of the page, so fixed-bottom elements are only shown at the bottom of the entire page (this is just one example -- any other viewport-height-relative elements won't display properly either).

Comment: I have tried using BoxWithConstraints, it worked with `verticalScroll` however it did make the WebView's screen fixed and not match its parent (as its supposed to be) :/

Comment: I thought the mess up of the WebView is a bug so I filed one. I got an answer from google real quick. They told me its not possible to achieve it this way and closed my bugreport as "Won't fix". They recommended using the "old" way with SwipeRefreshLayout which I did and it worked. It's a bit sad that there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and the Only valid way I think of is wrapping your `WebView` in a `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside the `AndroidView` Composable
here is my Solution:

```
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(
    viewModel: WebViewViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val refreshScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            SwipeRefreshLayout(context).apply {
                setOnRefreshListener {
                    refreshScope.launch {
                        refreshing = true
                        viewModel.webView.reload()
                        delay(1500)
                        refreshing = false
                    }

                }
                addView(viewModel.webView)
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            view.isRefreshing = refreshing
            viewModel.webView.loadUrl(viewModel.url)
        }
    )

}
```

in this example I put the WebView instance inside the viewModel for experimental resonse and for me to easily load the page in the web view because the update view will refere to the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun example(urlToRender: String) {
    val webViewState = rememberWebViewState(url = urlToRender)
    val webViewNavigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
    var webView by remember { mutableStateOf<WebView?>(null) }
    val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = false,
        onRefresh = { webViewNavigator.reload() }
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)
    ) {
        WebView(
            state = webViewState,
            navigator = webViewNavigator,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .scrollable(
                    rememberScrollableState(
                        consumeScrollDelta = { scroll ->
                            webView
                                ?.let { view ->
                                    val inverseScroll = -scroll
                                    val consumed = when {

                                        inverseScroll < 0 -> {
                                            inverseScroll.coerceAtLeast(-view.scrollY.toFloat())
                                        }

                                        inverseScroll > 0 -> {
                                            if (view.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                                                inverseScroll
                                            } else 0f
                                        }

                                        else -> 0f
                                    }
                                    view.scrollBy(0, consumed.roundToInt())
                                    -consumed
                                } ?: 0f
                        }
                    ),
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical
                ),
            onCreated = {
                webView = it
            }
        )
        PullRefreshIndicator(refreshing, pullRefreshState, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Aiham][1] answer, this seemed to work for us with webviews and avoiding the scroll issues mentioned above while still keeping the view full screen.

```
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(
    viewModel: WebViewViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val refreshScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            SwipeRefreshLayout(context).apply {
                viewModel.webView.setOnScrollChangeListener { view, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
                    isEnabled = scrollY == 0
                }
                setOnRefreshListener {
                    refreshScope.launch {
                        refreshing = true
                        viewModel.webView.reload()
                        delay(1500)
                        refreshing = false
                    }

                }
                addView(viewModel.webView)
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            view.isRefreshing = refreshing
            viewModel.webView.loadUrl(viewModel.url)
        }
    )
}


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78096034/1132441
```